# Implicit Sharing issue

Tags: sharing

Portal users can view the case's account because of implicit sharing which happens because we create case apex sharing records for these users. When we remove case apex sharing the users should stop have access to the case's account but the implicit sharing of the account stays. Even if the user doesn't have access to any of the account's cases anymore the implicit account sharing the record for that user stays.

The implicit sharing is not being automatically removed for some reason.

Anyone ever came across this problem? What is the root cause? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Access to child records of other objects besides Case could be the cause.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/129180)

Comment: @identigral Sure thing! Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @indentigral Thank you! Didn't help much, but we've noticed one thing: when we remove manual sharing using Apex (changing the account on the contact), implicit sharing removes as well. When we change account on the contact using the interface, implicit sharing stays. Weird, isn't it?